# Idempotent and positive definite operator implies self adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ but *maybe* is valid for any field) and $E$ a continuous operator. Suppose $E$ is idempotent, i.e.,$E^2=E$ and positive semi-definite, i.e. $(Ev,v) \geq 0$ for all $v$ (where $(.,.)$ means the internal product). Then $E$ is self adjoint.

I have proved $((E-E^*)v;v)=0$ for all $v $ quite easily but I don't know why that implies $E=E^*$ if the space is not necessarily complex. I guess you need to use the hypothesis $E$ idempotent.